# Epochs in a regenerative process

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

> A machine consists of two independent components, the $i$th of which functions for an exponential time with rate $\lambda_i$. The machine functions as long as at least one of these components function. When a machine fails, a new machine having both components working is put into use. A cost $K$ is incurred whenever a machine failure occurs; operating costs at rate $c_i$per unit time are incurred whenever the machine in use has $i$ working components, $i=1,2$. Find the long-run average cost per unit time.

Denote $T_1,T_2$ as the working time of component $1$ ans component $2$, respectively. Let $T$ be the time of a cycle. I was confused about $E[T]$.

My solution:
$$T_{\max}=\max\{T_1,T_2\}$$
$$E[T]=E[T_{\max}]=1/\lambda_1+1/\lambda_2-1/{(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)}$$
But the answer gives:
$$E[T]=E[\min\{T_1,T_2\}]+E[Y|T_1\ge T_2]P\{T_1\ge T_2\}+E[Y|T_1\lt T_2]P\{T_1\lt T_2\}$$
$$E[T] = \frac{1}{\lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2}} + \frac{1}{\lambda_{1}}\cdot\frac{\lambda_{2}}{\lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2}} + \frac{1}{\lambda_{2}}\cdot\frac{\lambda_{1}}{\lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2}}$$
and the $Y$ denotes the working time with only one component.

I can't find any mistakes in these two solutions, any help for this would be much appreciated :)

Comment: When the machine starts at time $t=0$, does it start using both components simultaneously, or does it first use component 1, and when that component fails, it starts using component 2 (or vice versa)?

Comment: @Thomsen I guess both components function at start, simultaneously.

Comment: Okay, I think that the two expressions should be the same, because $max(T_1,T_2) = min(T_1,T_2) + (T_1-T_2)^+ + (T_2-T_1)^+$ (where $(x)^+$ is the positive part of $x$) (see p. 428 in Ross: Intro to Probabilistic Models 8th ed.) Here $(T_1-T_2)^+$ corresponds to $E[Y|T_1>T_2]P(T_1>T_2)$, similarly for $(T_2-T_1)^+$.
So maybe its something with you computation of $E[max(T_1,T_2)]$.

Comment: The computation may be correct, this [document](http://math.illinoisstate.edu/krzysio/5-13-6-KO-Exercise.pdf) is for your reference

Comment: Sorry, I just found that they are actually the same, after a reduction to a common denominator.